# Keybinding a TextBox using XAML and WPF in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, key-bindings

I'm trying to bind to a key event in a WPF UserControl.  The component is a TextBox and my XAML is

```
<TextBox Name="textBarCode" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0"  Width="300">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding ImportPanel.BarcodeTextEnterKeyCommand}"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="Tab" Command="{Binding ImportPanel.BarcodeTextTabKeyCommand}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

I'm not sure if it is needed or not but the namespace declaration is

```
<UserControl x:Class="Scimatic.Samples.Actions.ImportPanel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml" 
    xmlns:components="clr-namespace:Scimatic.Mondrian.Components;assembly=Mondrian"
    xmlns:sampleInventory="clr-namespace:Scimatic.Mondrian.Views.SampleInventory;assembly=Mondrian"
    xmlns:trackingTags="clr-namespace:Scimatic.Mondrian.Views.TrackingTags;assembly=Mondrian">
```

The code that declares the command in the underlying xaml.cs file is

```
_barcodeKeyCommand = new ActionCommand(() =>
{
    if (!_parent && FocusableTagOnBarcode != null)
    {
        trackingInfo.SetFocusOnTag(FocusableTagOnBarcode);
    }
    else
    {
    buttonImport.Focus();
    }
});
```

The code that sets these properties is:

```
/// <summary>
/// The command property for the enter key in the barcode text box
/// </summary>
public ICommand BarcodeTextTabKeyCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _barcodeKeyCommand;
    }
}

The commands are returned in the same class using the same method:

/// <summary>
/// The command property for the enter key in the barcode text box
/// </summary>
public ICommand BarcodeTextEnterKeyCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _barcodeKeyCommand;
    }
}
```

However no matter what I try (and I've tried all kinds of things); I just cannot get the command to be called.  I've clearly done something wring but could someone please help me.  I'm fairly new to C# and I've wasted two days trying to respond to an enter key in a text box!

Thank you in advance,

Regards,

Neil

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `DataContext` of `TextBox` is an instance of something that has a `ImportPanel` property? How do you set `DataContext`? `ImportPanel` looks like a class name (your user control) and not property name

Comment: ImportPanel is a class name so I used that to specify the class and property; note I also tried removing that and just having the property name.  Both failed :(

Comment: Oh I'm not setting DataContext; my thinking went.  On the KeyEvent of Enter; it retrieves the command from the reference and executes it.  Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Binding will look for a specified binding `Path` in current binding context. By default it will be current `DataContext`. You can change binding context by using either `ElementName`, `Source` or `RelativeSource`. So in your case, assuming that `BarcodeTextEnterKeyCommand` is a property of `ImportPanel` control, you can give your control some name and then change command binding

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="Scimatic.Samples.Actions.ImportPanel"
    ...
    x:Name="myUserControl">
    <!-- ... -->
    <TextBox Name="textBarCode" ....>
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=BarcodeTextEnterKeyCommand}"/>
            <KeyBinding Key="Tab" Command="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=BarcodeTextEnterKeyCommand}"/>
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>
    <!-- ... -->
</UserControl>
```

Comment: thanks; it's getting late here so I'll try that tomorrow and if it's good I'll be sure to up vote.